# Getting Cannot GET /login when refleshing the page in heroku?

Tags: html, angular, heroku

Hi friends i've already uploaded my web site to heroku and it's working good but when i go to login route and reflesh the page i'm getting this error Cannot GET /login and on the console of my mozilla browser i'm getting this error as well.

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://vidrios-aluminio-naranjo.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico (“default-src”).`

Had anyone ever happend this? 
Any help for this?

[image: It's working fine and i can reflesh as well]

When i click on the login button i do go to there 
[image]

but if i wanna reload the page as others ones do it normally i get this error

`Cannot GET /login`

````
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://vidrios-aluminio-naranjo.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico (“default-src”). ```
````